# Power consumption of LD33CV voltage regulator

Tags: voltage, power, voltage-regulator

Does LD33CV voltage regulator consumes any power when there is no load? I used my multimeter and it shows the current flow as 0.00A without any load. But I feel my battery is draining out because of the voltage regulator

Comment: Read the datasheet, look up for quiescent current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LD33CV is the fixed 3.3V version of the [LM1117](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf).

See page 6. Quiescent current at 25°C is typically 5mA, and could be as much as 10mA. That's the current with no output current being drawn.

If your resolution on your meter is 0.01A then it may show zero.

That will drain a smallish battery fairly quickly.

Comment: any other alternative? I would like to have 3.3v regulator to power a component using 120mA MAX and 60mA typical.(5sec on mode and 55sec deepsleepmode)

Comment: @ACSreedharReddy google low quiescent current ldo, but something like https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP1810 may suit you, depending on how much power you need to dissipate.

Comment: Go to a distributor such as [this](https://www.digikey.in/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-regulators-linear/699?k=voltage%20regulator) one and do a parametric search setting Iq low (say < 10uA or 30uA) and also set maximum input voltage, output voltage 3.3V fixed, availability and output current, then read data sheets. Eg. NCV8705MT33TCG. MCP1700T-3302E/MAY MCP1810T-33I/J8A MCP1703T-3302E/MB TPS70633DRVR etc. etc. etc.